# Stop rails from escaping hstore array in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to use a postgreSQL column of type hstore array and everything seems to work just fine. However, my views escapes the array and turns it to bad formatted string. My code looks like that:

#### Migration:

```
class AddVariantsToItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore'
    add_column :items, :variants, :hstore, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

And now, if i will, for instance, use `Item.last.variants` in **rails console**, it gives me a proper array

```
> Item.last.variants
#=> [{"name"=>"Small", "price"=>"12.00"}, {"name"=>"Medium", "price"=>"20.00"}]
```

However, using the exact same code in slim views gives me a escaped string:

```
div
  = debug Item.last.variants

  / Gives me: 
  / '{"\"name\"=>\"Small\", \"price\"=>\"12.00\"","\"name\"=>\"Medium\", \"price\"=>\"20.00\""}'
```

Using `raw`, `==` or `.html_save` does not changes anything. Can anyone tell me if i can do anything about it?

Comment: What will you get with `Item.last.variants.to_yaml`?

Comment: It's not the same code - you're calling `debug`

Comment: well, `debug` gives me exact the same output as putting that variable into textarea value (which is what i need right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item.last.variants` is an Array. When putting something into view, its being stringified (I'm not sure, but I think its `to_s` method or `inspect`).

My advice is that you shouldn't put whole objects. In this particular example, I think you should iterate over it and show data manually.

Comment: Well, that issue is way more complex. I'm trying to post that array to angular controller using ng-init, that's why i needed that. However, i think it would be a better idea to use json api rather than hacking it this way. Thanks anyway.